# Is there difference between pipes from NIO and IO

Tags: java, io, nio, dataflow

I revise knowledge about I/O in java. Now I an introduce with pipes. I noticed that `java.io.*` have pipe mechanism and `java.nio.*` have similar mechanism.

I am reading some tutorials about these things. My current vision - pipes from NIO and pipes from I/O looks same. But I understand that it is strange to have duplicate things in JDK. Thus I think that I am wrong.

Can you clarify difference?

Answer (score 2):

IO is stream-oriented, NIO is buffer-oriented.

IO streams are blocking, NIO has non-blocking mode.

In this [Java NIO Tutorial (by Jakob Jenkov)](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html) you find background and examples. It also helps you finding the best approach on your case.

Comment: NIO doesn't have streams, but it can be blocking: indeed, it is blocking by default. It can also be asynchronous.

Comment: If someone can show difference on cocrete example -it would be good